# How to implement an apache wicket server side thread

Tags: java, wicket

I am new to Apache wicket. As I understand there is a new thread for each user connected to my website. Im making a website about events(like facebook events) where users can join and leave them and I want to create a thread that checks all events every hour and informs event participants if the event is happening soon. I want only 1 thread on all users or for it to run server side even if no users are connected, not for a user to have its separate thread. How should I do that?

Allready found answer myself,I needed to put a new thread that does what i want in the Application.init() method.

Comment: Just as a comment, I would run this kind of programmed threads (or batch processing) outside the ApplicationServer on a separate JVM. Maybe you could start these processes with a crontab?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use org.apache.wicket.IApplicationListener for some additional stuff that should be done in background. Just start your thread in onAfterInitialized and stop it in onBeforeDestroyed.

But if you use EAR/J2EE/Sprint there is better ways to perform this kind of tasks: @Scheduled (in Spring) or look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html